# .net Regex.Split

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to split the following string `"Name=='mynme' && CurrentTime<'2012-04-20 19:45:45'"` into this:

```
Name
==
'myname'
&&
CurrentTime
<
'2012-04-20 19:45:45'
```

I have the following regex:

```
([+\\-*/%()]{1}|[=<>!]{1,2}|[&|]{2})
```

The problem is when using the above regex I get the following result:

```
Name
== 
'myname'
&&
CurrentTime 
<
'2012
-
04
-
20
19:45:45'
```

I practically need the regex to be quote aware.

Thanks

***Update 1 regarding lordcheeto's answer:***

Your response is close. But the following is still not split correctly:

```
 string input2 = "((1==2) && 2-1==1) || 3+1==4 && Name=='Stefan+123'";
```

What I need to do is to split a string into operators and operands. Something like this:

```
 LeftOperand Operator RightOperand
```

Now, if any operator is between `''` it should be ignored and the whole string between `''` should be treated as an operand.

The string above should generate the following output:

```
(

(
1
==
2
)

&&
2
-
1
==
1
)

||
3
+
1
==
4
&&
Name
==
'Stefan+123'
```

Comment: Just edited it, should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, assuming you want it to simply split on logical and relational operators, you can use this pattern:

```
string lordcheeto = @"\s*(==|&&|<=|>=|<|>)\s*";
```

This will also trim all whitespace from the returned strings.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegEx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string original = "([+\\-*/%()]{1}|[=<>!]{1,2}|[&|]{2})";
            string lordcheeto = @"\s*(==|&&|<=|>=|<|>)\s*";

            string input = "Name=='mynme' && CurrentTime<45 - 4";
            string input1 = "Name=='mynme' && CurrentTime<'2012-04-20 19:45:45'";
            string ridiculous = "Name == BLAH && !@#>=$%^&*()< ASDF &&    this          >          that";

            executePattern("original", input, original);
            executePattern("lordcheeto's", input, lordcheeto);
            executePattern("original", input1, original);
            executePattern("lordcheeto's", input1, lordcheeto);
            executePattern("original", ridiculous, original);
            executePattern("lordcheeto's", ridiculous, lordcheeto);
        }

        static void executePattern(string version, string input, string pattern)
        {
            // Avoiding repitition for this example.
            Console.WriteLine("Using {0} pattern:", version);

            // Needs to be trimmed.
            var result = Regex.Split(input.Trim(), pattern);

            // Pipes included to highlight whitespace trimming.
            foreach (var m in result)
                Console.WriteLine("|{0}|", m);

            // Extra space.
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test:**

http://goo.gl/XAm6J

**Output:**

```
Using original pattern:
|Name|
|==|
|'mynme' |
|&&|
| CurrentTime|
|<|
|45 |
|-|
| 4|


Using lordcheeto's pattern:
|Name|
|==|
|'mynme'|
|&&|
|CurrentTime|
|<|
|45 - 4|


Using original pattern:
|Name|
|==|
|'mynme' |
|&&|
| CurrentTime|
|<|
|'2012|
|-|
|04|
|-|
|20 19:45:45'|


Using lordcheeto's pattern:
|Name|
|==|
|'mynme'|
|&&|
|CurrentTime|
|<|
|'2012-04-20 19:45:45'|


Using original pattern:
|Name |
|==|
| BLAH |
|&&|
| |
|!|
|@#|
|>=|
|$|
|%|
|^&|
|*|
||
|(|
||
|)|
||
|<|
| ASDF |
|&&|
|    this          |
|>|
|          that|


Using lordcheeto's pattern:
|Name|
|==|
|BLAH|
|&&|
|!@#|
|>=|
|$%^&*()|
|<|
|ASDF|
|&&|
|this|
|>|
|that|
```

---

### Edit

Ok, with the additional constraints, you should be able to use this:

```
string lordcheeto = @"\s*('.*?'|&&|==|<=|>=|<|>|\(|\)|\+|-|\|\|)\s*";
```

This will still trim all whitespace from the returned strings. It will, however, return empty strings if matches are right next to each other (e.g. `Name=='Stefan+123'`). I was unable to work around that this time, but it's not so important.

If you import `System.Linq` and `System.Collections.Generic` and make the results a `List<string>`, you can remove all empty strings from the `List` in one extra line like this (which is slower than using straight-up for loops):

```
var results = Regex.Split(input.Trim(), pattern).ToList();
results.RemoveAll(x => x == "");
```

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegEx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string lordcheeto = @"\s*('.*?'|&&|==|<=|>=|<|>|\(|\)|\+|-|\|\|)\s*";

            string input = "Name=='mynme' && CurrentTime<45 - 4";
            string input1 = "Name=='mynme' && CurrentTime<'2012-04-20 19:45:45'";
            string input2 = "((1==2) && 2-1==1) || 3+1==4 && Name=='Stefan+123'";

            executePattern("lordcheeto's", input, lordcheeto);
            executePattern("lordcheeto's", input1, lordcheeto);
            executePattern("lordcheeto's", input2, lordcheeto);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void executePattern(string version, string input, string pattern)
        {
            // Avoiding repitition for this example.
            Console.WriteLine("Using {0} pattern:", version);

            // Needs to be trimmed.
            var result = Regex.Split(input.Trim(), pattern);

            // Pipe included to highlight empty strings.
            foreach (var m in result)
                Console.WriteLine("|{0}", m);

            // Extra space.
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test:**

http://goo.gl/lkaoM

**Output:**

```
Using lordcheeto's pattern:
|Name
|==
|
|'mynme'
|
|&&
|CurrentTime
|<
|45
|-
|4


Using lordcheeto's pattern:
|Name
|==
|
|'mynme'
|
|&&
|CurrentTime
|<
|
|'2012-04-20 19:45:45'
|


Using lordcheeto's pattern:
|
|(
|
|(
|1
|==
|2
|)
|
|&&
|2
|-
|1
|==
|1
|)
|
|||
|3
|+
|1
|==
|4
|&&
|Name
|==
|
|'Stefan+123'
|
```

**Additional Comments:**

If you want to split on any other operators (e.g., `<<`, `+=`,`=`, `-=`, `>>`) as well (there's [a lot](http://goo.gl/39KYB)), or need anything else, just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. PLease see my Update on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks "lordcheeto" for the answer I was able to solve similar problem with your solution. I am sharing my problem and solution just in case of helping anyone with similar problem.

I have to split string like

```
"abc < 1 && 124 > 2 || 1243 <= 555";
```

First Into

```
abc < 1
&&
124 > 2
||
1243 <= 555
```

I have achieve this by using

```
string[] condtions = Regex.Split(str, @"\s*('.*?'|&&|\|\|)\s*");
```

Then I have to split each condition like

```
abc < 1
```

Into

```
abc
<
1
```

I achieved this by using

```
string[] statements = Regex.Split(condtions[0], @"\s*('.*?'|==|<=|>=|<|>|!=)\s*");
```